# How to configure maven in play framework 2.5.4?

Tags: java, maven, playframework-2.5

I want to configure my project play framework 2.5.4 with maven configuration.
And at the same time I want to generate a war file using the maven,
so I want help to configure.

I've added plugin in plugin.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "2.5.4")
```

and in bulid.sbt

```
Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings
Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "3.1"
```

While compiling my project it shows issues like

```
[warn]  module not found: com.github.play2war#play2-war-plugin;2.5.4
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.github.play2war/play2-war-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.play2war/play2-war-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\sarathb\.ivy2\local\com.github.play2war\play2-war-plugin\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\2.5.4\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/play2war/play2-war-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.5.4/play2-war-plugin-2.5.4.pom
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   C:\activator-1.3.10-minimal\repository\com.github.play2war\play2-war-plugin\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\2.5.4\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   C:\activator-dist-1.3.10\repository\com.github.play2war\play2-war-plugin\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\2.5.4\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/github/play2war/play2-war-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.5.4/play2-war-plugin-2.5.4.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.github.play2war/play2-war-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.play2war#play2-war-plugin;2.5.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.github.play2war:play2-war-plugin:2.5.4 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.github.play2war:play2-war-plugin:2.5.4 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (C:\play\project\plugins.sbt#L24-25)
[warn]            +- default:play-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
```

and when I run maven build in eclipse:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[3,20] package javax.inject does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[5,31] package org.apache.commons.mail does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[7,16] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[8,16] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[11,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Controller
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[3,31] package org.apache.commons.mail does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[4,31] package org.apache.commons.mail does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[5,31] package org.apache.commons.mail does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[7,16] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[8,16] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[10,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Controller
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[21,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Result
  location: class controllers.UserController
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[21,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EmailException
  location: class controllers.UserController
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[13,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Result
  location: class services.MailController
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[13,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EmailException
  location: class services.MailController
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[1,1] package javax.inject does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[2,1] package play does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[3,16] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[4,17] package play.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[5,1] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[7,15] cannot access filters.ExampleFilter
  bad source file: C:\play\app\filters\ExampleFilter.java
    file does not contain class filters.ExampleFilter
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[15,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Inject
  location: class controllers.UserController
[INFO] 22 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.981 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-23T11:27:32+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project play: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[3,20] package javax.inject does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[5,31] package org.apache.commons.mail does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[7,16] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[8,16] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[11,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Controller
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[3,31] package org.apache.commons.mail does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[4,31] package org.apache.commons.mail does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[5,31] package org.apache.commons.mail does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[7,16] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[8,16] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[10,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Controller
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[21,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Result
[ERROR] location: class controllers.UserController
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[21,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EmailException
[ERROR] location: class controllers.UserController
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[13,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Result
[ERROR] location: class services.MailController
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/services/MailController.java:[13,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EmailException
[ERROR] location: class services.MailController
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[1,1] package javax.inject does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[2,1] package play does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[3,16] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[4,17] package play.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[5,1] package play.mvc does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/Filters.java:[7,15] cannot access filters.ExampleFilter
[ERROR] bad source file: C:\play\app\filters\ExampleFilter.java
[ERROR] file does not contain class filters.ExampleFilter
[ERROR] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/controllers/UserController.java:[15,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Inject
[ERROR] location: class controllers.UserController
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Suggest me any sample code or your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency can't be resolved because the version you've declared doesn't exist. As you can see in the [project documentation](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin) play2-war-plugin has different version numbers than play version has:

> Current versions:
>
> Play 2.2.x          : 1.2.1
>      Play 2.3.0 -> 2.3.1 : 1.3-beta1 (Scala 2.10 & 2.11)
>
> Play 2.3.2+         : 1.3-beta3 (Scala 2.10 & 2.11)
>
> Play 2.4.x          : 1.4-beta1 (Scala 2.10 & 2.11)
>
> Play 2.5.x          : Not supported yet

As you can see Play `2.5.x` is not supported yet. For Play `2.4.x` your plugin.sbt file would look like

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" %% "play2-war-plugin" % "1.4-beta1")
```

Comment: ok but in play 2.5.X if we want to create a war file what we have to do? any idea....

Comment: and if we build a project using maven in eclipse it shows an error as above. for this any solution

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do it for play 2.5.x. All solutions that I know of only support Play up to 2.4.x as of now: https://github.com/absurdhero/play-pure-maven-plugin, https://orrsella.com/2014/02/25/integrating-play-framework-and-maven/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write, how you configured your Maven build.

Anyway, you can use Maven Plugin for Play 2.x (https://github.com/play2-maven-plugin/play2-maven-plugin).

Example WAR project for Play! 2.4.x and Servlet API 3.1 is here: https://github.com/play2-maven-plugin/play2-maven-test-projects/tree/master/play24/war/helloworld-war-servlet-3.1
It uses `com.github.play2war:play2-war-core-servlet31_2.11` artifact published by play2-war-plugin. As already mentioned, Play 2.5.x is not supported (yet?).